# dimension of linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a linear subspace of $V$. Show that $\dim_K(U)\leq \dim_K(V)$ and conclude, that $\dim_K(U)= \dim_K(V) \Leftrightarrow U = V$. Is the equivalence $\dim_K(U)= \dim_K(V) \Leftrightarrow U = V$ also true for $\dim_K(V)= \infty$?

I've proved so far that $\dim_K(U)= \dim_K(V) \Leftrightarrow U = V$,but i have no idea, if this is still true for $\dim_K(V)= \infty$.   I have problems to show that  $\dim_K(U)\leq \dim_K(V)$ (doesn't this follow by definition?)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let the $V$ the subspace of $\mathbb R[x]$ defined by
$$V=\mathrm{span}\left\{x^{2n},\ n\in\mathbb N\right\}$$
Prove that $V\varsubsetneq \mathbb R[x]$. What's $\dim V?$

Comment: How can i prove that $V\varsubsetneq \mathbb R[x]$?

Comment: Can you  write $x$ as linear combination of elements of $V$?

Comment: No, because $n$ has to be $n\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Any linear combination of $V$ is an even polynomial so the odd polynomial isn't in $V$.

Comment: And the dimension of $V$ is infinite?

Comment: Assume the contrary and let $m$ the maximal degree of the polynomials in a basis of $V$. Can you write $x^{m+2}$ as linear combination of the elements of this basis?

Comment: No, because $x^m$ is the highest polynomial in V.

Comment: This deserves an upvote! $+\uparrow$

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_U$ be a basis for $U$.  Then $B_U$ is an independent subset of $V$, and hence (assuming that $V$ has a basis) may be extended to a basis for $V$, which has cardinality at least as large as $|B_U|=dim_K(U)$.

If both vector spaces are infinite-dimensional it need not be true that they are equal.  For example, consider $V=P(t)$, the set of all polynomials in $t$, and $U=tP(t)$, the set of all polynomials in $t$ with constant term equal to zero.